# switch statement gone wrong - swift language

Tags: switch-statement, swift

in Obj-c i made a switch statement which i used to move around in my app for iPad using UIsplitviewcontroller 
now i want to do the same in swift... i tried for a couple of hours and now the only thing i haven't been able to try is the code because it says some sort of compile error
anyway
here's what i got in Obj-c

```
-(void)initialSite:(int)viewId {
UIViewController *viewController;
switch (viewId) {
    case 0:{
        viewController = self.initital;
        NSString *star = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Velkommen til %@'s  Bog",[data valueForKey:@"navn"]];
        self.navigationItem.title = star;}
        break;
    case 1:{
        viewController = self.startSide;
        NSString *start = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s  Bog, start-side",[data valueForKey:@"navn"]];
        self.navigationItem.title = start;}
        break;
}
[self showChildViewController:viewController];

}
```

and here's what i come up with so far in swift. still new to this and to understand it is a little hard even tho i have the swift programming language book

here's what i got so far in swift

```
    let viewController = UIViewController()
switch viewController {
case "initial":
let initial : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc0 : UIViewController = initial.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("initial") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc0, animated: true, completion: nil)
let rowData: NSDictionary = self.menuItemArray[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary!
self.navigation.title = rowData["navn"] as? String

case "startSide":
let startSide : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc1 : UIViewController = startSide.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("startSide") as UIViewController
let rowData: NSDictionary = self.manuItemArray[indexPath.row] as NSDictionary!
self.presentViewController(vc1, animated: true, completion: nil)
self.navigation.title = rowData["navn"] as? String
default:


}
```

the error is : ***Expected declaration*** at the line with 
    ***let viewController = UIViewcontroller()***

Comment: What you created in Swift looks nothing like your Obj-C version. For example, why are you passing `viewController` into your switch statement and comparing it against `Strings`? Are you trying to create the exact same thing in Swift as you have in the above example?

Comment: @Firo yes i'm trying to recreate the above example from obj-c to swift. but having a hard time understanding swift

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with your Obj-C implementation:

```
-(void)initialSite:(int)viewId 
{
    UIViewController *viewController;
    switch (viewId) 
    {
        case 0:
        {
            viewController = self.initital;
            NSString *star = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Velkommen til %@'s  Bog",[data valueForKey:@"navn"]];
            self.navigationItem.title = star;
        }
        break;
        case 1:
        {
            viewController = self.startSide;
            NSString *start = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s  Bog, start-side",[data valueForKey:@"navn"]];
            self.navigationItem.title = start;
        }
        break;
    }

    [self showChildViewController:viewController];
}
```

Now this same snippet in Swift:

```
func initialSite(viewID:Int)
{
    var viewController : UIViewController?

    switch (viewID)
    {
        case 0:
            viewController = self.initial
            let navn = self.data["navn"] as? String
            let star = "Velkommen til \(navn)'s Bog"
            self.navigationItem.title = star

        case 1:
            viewController = self.startSide
            let navn = self.data["navn"] as? String
            let star = "\(navn)'s Bog, start-side"
            self.navigationItem.title = star

        default:
            viewController = nil
            // do nothing
    }

    self.showChildViewController(viewController)
}
```

The main thing you have to remember is the difference with `var` vs `let`. Typically you will use `let` to create things unless those things will have their value changed later, which you use `var`.

The other thing is the use of optionals, with the `?` suffix. This is when the value may be `nil` (unset), otherwise it must contain a value.

Comment: Also, that swift `case`s can be multiple lines without use of `{ }`.  If their use is attempted as in the Obj-C example, a `Closure expression is unused` error arises.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like SiLo beat me to it. Anyway I have my solution so I will post it. This is how I would do it:

```
func initialSite(viewId: Int) -> () {
    var viewController: UIViewController?
    let dataValue = data["navn"];
    var start: String?

    switch viewId {
        case 1:
            viewController = self.initital
            start = "Velkommen til \(dataValue)'s  Bog"
        case 2:
            viewController = self.startSide
            start = "\(dataValue)'s  Bog, start-side"
        default:
            break;
    }

    self.navigationItem.title = start!
    showChildViewController(viewController!)
}
```

Comment: Surely some mistake in the re declaration of `start`? The inner `let` declarations will obscure the outer `var` meaning it will remain unset...